# Postgres - The transaction has already committed locally, but might not have been replicated to the standby

Tags: postgresql

What I have done. I have one production database server (DB) 10.0.0.10 and one replica (Main_A).

`pg_basebackup -h 10.0.0.10 -U replication_user -X stream -C -S main_a -v -R -W -D /var/lib/postgresql/10`

This database is old, I know.
Now I would like to build a new cluster based on pglogical (test only). So I promote Main_A to be production server. Install pglogical, etc.

Question is. Why when I put command there is any standby?

`CREATE EXTENSION pglogical;`

It's hang so what I have to do is CTRL+C and in logs I see

`WARNING:  canceling wait for synchronous replication due to user request`

`DETAIL:  The transaction has already committed locally, but might not have been replicated to the standby.`

I don't see any records in pg_stat_wal_receiver. I already comment my replication user in pg_hba.conf and use pg_reload_conf() to reload.

I have upgraded this database to pg13 but same effect.

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by changing configuration in postgres.conf
`synchronous_standby_names = ''`
old settings was
`synchronous_standby_names = '*'`